# InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Mul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int32 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Mul] name: mul/

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model

I instantiate a class and get some errors when passing in parameters.saying that the data type received not the expected type

i try to convert the data to the type it requires but get the same error

```
class PositionalEmbedding(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, d_model, dropout, max_len=5000):
  super(PositionalEmbedding,self).__init__()
  self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout,dtype = 'float32')

  pe = tf.zeros([max_len,d_model],dtype = 'float32')
  position = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(max_len),axis = 1)
```

pe = PositionalEmbedding(20,0)

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
      2 
----> 3 pe = PositionalEmbedding(20,0)
      4 
      5 s = pe(tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1,100,20)))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Mul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int32 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:Mul] name: mul/

Answer (score 1):

What tensorflow version are you using? Works as written for me in tf 2.0 and tf 1.14 (sorry don't have enough rep to put this as a comment)

n.b. I'm assuming that to correct the indentation this is what you actually meant, because any other correction makes some of the lines redundant...but please correct if that's wrong

```py
    class PositionalEmbedding(tf.keras.Model):
        def __init__(self, d_model, dropout, max_len=5000):
             super(PositionalEmbedding,self).__init__()
             self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout,dtype = 'float32')

             pe = tf.zeros([max_len,d_model],dtype = 'float32')
             position = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(max_len),axis = 1)

    pe = PositionalEmbedding(20, 0)
```

Comment: i use tf version is 2.0,can you help me to solve it

Answer (score 1):

The problem may not be due to the variables of the model but due to the input.
Convert input of your model to float32.

1. If input is numpy array

```
inp = inp.astype('float32')
```

2. If input is tensor

```
inp = tf.cast(inp, tf.float32)
```

Comment: Note that `input` shadows the built-in function `input()`. Consider using a different name for your variable.